# Mask brush in Texture Paint missing stencil

Tags: masking, brushes, texture-paint-mode

Hi I'm hoping this will be simple, but i couldn't find a thread about this exact issue. I'm just trying to use the 'mask brush' option next to the other brushes in Texture Paint (NOT sculpting) just so i can get a better angle on my model without worrying about painting onto other parts.

When I try to select the mask brush, i get a missing stencil error. I'm sure I just have to create a new material or something specifically for masking, but I'm hoping someone can tell me the exact steps so I don't mess anything up especially because I still get a little confused with node setups.

I don't want to use face select for masking because my mesh is really dense at the moment. If someone can just walk me through the steps with photos i'll be forever grateful!
[image]

[image]